# ADB pulling files from /data/data fails due to symlinks. How to skip symlinks in ADB pull?

Tags: adb, backup

I can run

```
adb pull /data/data/com.xlythe.saolauncher/databases ./
```

or

```
adb pull /data/data/com.xlythe.saolauncher/files ./
```

and it works fine. However, if I try

```
adb pull /data/data/com.xlythe.saolauncher ./
```

It fails with the error:

> adb: error: failed to copy '/data/data/com.xlythe.saolauncher/lib' to
>   './com.xlythe.saolauncher/lib': remote No such file or directory

It happens because the `lib` folder is actually a symlink to `/data/app-lib/com.xlythe.saolauncher`

Now, if I wanted only `com.xlythe.saolauncher` I would just do it by hand copying one folder at time, but I want instead to pull all `/data/data` at once.
So I need a way to tell ADB to just skip symlinks instead of failing the copy.
Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Method 1:

If you're okay with getting the output file as a `.tar` archive, try this command:

> adb exec-out tar c data/data > data_backup.tar

Make sure to omit the leading `/` in your path. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14934666/5002496))

### Method 2:

If you want to copy file-wise, use the following script written by me:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Run as: ./filename.sh <source_folder> <destination_folder>
## If no <destination_folder> is provided, it's stored in current directory.

location=$1
if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    destination=.
else
  destination=$2
fi

## Find the full path of all the files in the given directory, and retrieve each file one by one

while read line
do
  ## Create the directory where the file will reside, by removing the filename alone from the fullpath.
  ## Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022471/5002496
  mkdir -p $destination"${line%/*}"
  adb pull $line $destination$line
done <<< `adb shell find $location -type f`

## The find binary in Android doesn't seem to show symlinks when '-type f' option is used.
## Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16303559/5002496
```

Save it as `adb_pull.sh`, run `chmod 777 adb_pull.sh` and run it like:

> ./adb_pull.sh /data/data data_backup

All the contents from `/data/data` from Android device will be stored into `data_backup` folder.
(*Note*: **DON'T** specify the source folder like `/data/data/` with an additional `/` after the folder name)

Tested and working on my Ubuntu 17.04, using an Android 7.1 device.
Note: To access `/data` partition completely via ADB, you need to run `adb root`. ([more help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175368/5002496)..)

Comment: +1 I had to join this site just to give an upvote to this answer (Method 1) which really helped me. :)

Comment: Creating a `tar` archive may fail because of combining stdout and stderr. Try `adb shell 'tar -cf - data 2>/dev/null' | gzip -9 > backup.tar.gz` instead.